# Create a new task that runs a program

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to define a custom tasks that computes the name of a main class and then runs it. I was thinking about something like this

```
customTask {
  mainClass = compute main class name based on env
  runMain(mainClass, jvm-args, fork=true)
}
```

and then in SBT i would be able to run

> sbt> custom-task

can this be done in SBT 11.2 ?.

Comment: Are you stuck on 0.11? If you can upgrade to 0.13, see visual's answer. On 0.11, the short version is that you can't reuse the `runMain` task, instead, you look at the sbt source code, see what calls that task does, and then do those same calls in your own task.

Answer (score 3):

well you can give it a try .. I works fine for me -

```
lazy val testngRun = inputKey[Unit]("custom run task for testng")

testngRun := {
    val one = (runMain in Compile).fullInput(" org.testng.TestNG -testclass com.pg.acceptance.testcase.PfsLoginServiceTest").evaluated
}
```

Comment: Note that the `fullInput` method wasn't added to sbt until version 0.13.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can create new SBT tasks as mentioned in documentation http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks#defining-a-new-task

You can run any scala code as the task code. Tasks can also take input arguments.

Pretty much powerful IMO.

Comment: The linked documentation is fine, but one should pay attention to the version combo box on top of the page, because there are considerable differences between the different sbt versions.

Comment: The problem here though is reusing functionality from an existing input task such as `runMain`. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/407