# Custom sbt task to run tests by tag

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I want to do some sbt custom tasks for running tests (scalatest) by tag. For example: now I can run this in the sbt console:

```
sbt test-only -- -n UnitTests
```

I want to run this doing something like

```
sbt test-unit // or something like that
```

I also want to do the same by excluding tests

sbt test-only -- -l ExternalTests

to:

```
sbt test-exclude-external
```

For accomplishing that I'm trying to create a custom sbt task... but i don't know how to do the `-- -l` stuff

```
val testUnit = taskKey[Unit]("Launch unit tests")
testUnit := {
  // sbt test-only -- -n UnitTests
  //(test in Test)
}
```

It will be useful if also I can run tests by namespace in a custom sbt task:

```
sbt testOnly integration.actors.*
```

Can you help me guys? I'm a little newbie with sbt :(

Answer (score 4):

fullInput does not work well with "in Test". I've finally did this:

```
val unit = taskKey[Unit]("Launch unit tests")
unit := {
  (testOnly in Test).toTask(s" com.trololo.unit.*").value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `fullInput` as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702863/create-a-new-task-that-runs-a-program).
Also, possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151028/sbt-pre-applying-input-to-inputkeys).